# What is the way to describe the type signature of Haskell functions that are not type-specific?

Tags: function, haskell, types, type-signature, haskell-prelude

Given a function like `negate`, it has the type signature:

```
negate :: Num a => a -> a
```

which I would describe as `a` being the type in the context of `Num` (correct me if you think I am wrong).

But I not fully sure how to describe something like `last`, which has the type signature:

```
last :: [a] -> a
```

My guess would be to say it isn't type-specific, and that it takes a list and produces a single value of the same type as the list. Is this the correct way to think about it?

Comment: `Num a` is a "constraint", `Num` is a "type class" / "typeclass", `a -> a` is a "parametrically-polymorphic type", `a` is a "type variable" ( the  "parameter" in the ["parametrically-polymorphic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Parametric_polymorphism) ). `[b] -> b` is a parametrically-polymorphic type, `[b]` is a parametrically-polymorphic type, `b` is a type variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, `a` is not *the* type in the context of `Num`, but *a* type that has a `Num` instance.

`Num a => a -> a` is a *constrained* polymorphic type, while `[a] -> a` is an unconstrained polymorphic type, or just polymorphic type for short. In the unconstrained case, `a` can be any type; in the constrained case, it must be a type that obeys the given constraints.

Answer (score 3):

In `negate` you need to *operate* on the element passed, in your case you could apply some operator to it, e.g. `(-)`: `negate a = -a`.

You cannot define `negate` for *any* type, because you need to be able to call `(-)` on it. You need some *guarantee* that the argument given will be of some type which *supports* this operation.

`Num` is a type class which gives you exactly this - a compile-time guarantee that `(-)` is supported, and other functions like `+`, `*`, too. You can read more about it in the [docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num)

In contrast, `last :: [a] -> a` does *not* (need to) do anything on the actual `a` values. It only accepts them and returns the last one. While `negate` operates on the `a` value, here `last` operates on the *list*, but does not do anything to its values, it only passes them around. Therefore, it does not need *any* knowledge about them, and so the type is unconstrained.

Comment: or you could be defining `a - b = a + (negate b)`.

Answer (score 0):

`last :: [a] -> a` is the Haskell98 syntax for the [System F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F) type

```
last :: ∀ a. [a] -> a
```

The `∀ a` can be understood as a kind of type-level lambda binding, i.e. before the actual value level list parameter the function accepts a type-level argument telling what the type of elements contained in the list. This *universal quantification* makes the function *parametrically polymorphic*.

Normally, the type variables are automatically inserted by the type checker. In newer GHC Haskell, you can also explicitly apply them:

```
Prelude> :set -XTypeApplications 
Prelude> :t last @Int
last @Int :: [Int] -> Int
Prelude> last @Double [5,6,7]
7.0
```

`negate` is also parametrically polymorphic, but unlike `last` it does not work truely “for all” types, but only for those that have a `Num` instance (which both `Int` and `Double` do, but not e.g. `Char`). In other words, it accepts not only an extra argument *specifying* the type, but also a *proof* that it does indeed have a `Num` instance. That too will be inserted automatically by the compiler.

```
negate :: ∀ a. Num a => a -> a
```

```
Prelude> :t negate @Int
negate @Int :: Int -> Int
Prelude> :t negate @Char

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    No instance for (Num Char) arising from a use of ‘negate’
```